# application configured to with keycloak sso ,keycloak is behind apache proxy server gives too many redirects

Tags: apache2, keycloak

I have a wildfly application configured to work with keycloak sso , this application works fine,
now we have to have a apache server acting as proxy before the keycloak and wildflyserver.this is the configuration file for apache , when hit in browser it gives too many redirects , do I need to configure anything in keycloak side or apache side ?

```
#NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
     
ServerAdmin postmaster@xxx.yyy.icg
DocumentRoot "c:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.yyy.com"
ServerName xxx.yyy.com
ServerAlias www.xxx.yyy.com
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
     SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
     SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
SSLEngine on      
     SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/app.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/cert.key"
ErrorLog "logs/xxx.yyy.com-error.log"
     CustomLog "logs/xxx.yyy.com-error.log" combined
ProxyPass        "/" "http://10.0.144.246:8060/app1"
     ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://10.0.144.246:8060/app1"

<Location /app1>
ProxyPass http://http://10.0.144.246:8060/app1
ProxyPassReverse http://10.0.144.246:8060/app1
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Location>


</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

We experienced the exact same issue with the similar setup of Keycloak and NGINX and we managed to fix it by enabling the sticky session on NGINX.